# iteration over python nested lists

Tags: python, list, nested, nested-lists

I need to convert list 'a'  to list 'b' ,
how to do it?

```
a = [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12,]]]

b = [[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12,]]]
```

Comment: In a more easy way? What was the hard  way? Please include what you have tried in your question.

Comment: can you elaborate what you really what to do? I assume you need to convert the list a  into list b

Comment: a = [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12,]]]
c = [[], []]         for j in range(len(a)):
    for i in range(len(a[j])):
        c[j].extend(a[j][i])
print('c', c)    # I did that way, but i think is ugly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a neat trick with `sum()` to join nested lists:

```
[[sum(l, [])] for l in a]
#[[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]]
```

---

Just to make it clearer why this works, consider the following example:

```
>>> sum([[1,2], [3,4]], [])
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

---

Or you could use the more efficient `itertools.chain_from_iterable` method:

```
flatten = itertools.chain.from_iterable
[[list(flatten(l))] for l in a]
#[[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]]
```

Comment: Don't use `sum` to flatten a list.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Why not?

Comment: Here's the [gist](https://gist.github.com/juanarrivillaga/0ed8e599cbc8a8605abbe919df84c5fa) of it. Although, `sum` may have been optimized for strings in a recent version (like 3.6 maybe)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Wow! Never knew the performance difference would be that drastic - thanks for making that visualisation. I dropped a comment about the source if you could have a peep :)

Comment: Yeah, concatenation with sequences is generally linear time with the python built-ins. so doing it in a loop is quadratic time. I think its just a pattern to avoid, it may not significantly affect the performance of the code depending on the actual shape of the nested lists, i.e. if the number of inner lists is expected to be small.

Comment: thanks a lot! with itertools is the best way for  nsted list of any shape

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the follow list comprehension:

```
In [1]: a = [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12,]]]
   ...:

In [2]: [[[a for sub in nested for a in sub]] for nested in a]
Out[2]: [[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]]
```

It is equivalent to the following nested for-loop:

```
result = []
for nested in a:
    _temp = []
    for sub in nested:
        for a in sub:
            _temp.append(a)
    result.append([_temp])
```

Although, I would write it more like:

```
result = []
for nested in a:
    _temp = []
    for sub in nested:
        _temp.extend(sub)
    result.append([_temp])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension: This assumes that you have only two sub-sublists within each sublist. Since you are very clear in your input and output, it does what you want

```
a = [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12,]]]
b = [[c[0] + c[1]] for c in a ]
print (b)
```

**Output**

```
[[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]]
```

Comment: thanks for answer, I'm sorry, I don't mention before that actual list 'a' too big. it contains 60000 nested list inside. I just write  small sample list. so i see list comprehension nicely resolve problem for  small list, but what about big one?

Comment: You mean instead of `c[0]` and `c[1]` you have elements going up to `c[59999]`?

Comment: thanks for answer, I'm sorry, that I don't mention before that actual list 'a' too big. list shape is  1 x 60000 x 25 x 3. I just write  small sample list. so i see list comprehension nicely resolve problem for  small list, but what about big one?

Answer (score 0):

Another way of achieving concatenation of two lists is the following:

```
a = [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12,]]]

b = list(map(lambda elem: [[*elem[0], *elem[1]]],a))
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a loop method.

```
a = [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12,]]]
b = []
for i in a:
    new_j = []
    for j in i:
        new_j.extend(j)
    new_i = [new_j]
    b = b + [new_i]
b
```